I am using Expo Router v3. version 51 and for whatever reason I am getting a white screen
Issue:
Everything works perfectly when I run my Expo app using npx expo start and open it in Expo Go. However, I encounter a white screen when I push the app to TestFlight. The same issue happens when I build the app via the "preview" lane in the Expo Developer Portal and launch it through Expo Go, resulting in a white screen.
Additionally, when I try running the app in Xcode, I get an error related to Hermes. I believe my provisioning profiles are set up correctly, as I successfully pushed the app to App Store Connect (despite the white screen issue).
I had a working version of the app on TestFlight a few months ago, but I’m unsure what could have changed to cause the white screen now.
What I've Tried:

npx expo-doctor reports no issues—everything works fine.
There are no errors during the EAS build process.
I've tried various commands and builds, but I can’t remember every single one I've used. The ones I do remember include:

eas build -p ios --profile preview
eas build -p ios --profile production (to test the production version)



I'm now asking here, hoping to get some direction on troubleshooting this issue. I just need a way to log what's happening when running the app on a physical device or simulator outside Expo Go.
Please let me know if you need additional information or specific diagnostics, and I will update the question with the necessary details or commands.
Here’s my eas.json file:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 12.5.2",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "development"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "channel": "preview",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "production"
      }
    },
    "staging": {
      "channel": "staging",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "credentialsSource": "remote"
      },
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "staging"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production",
      "distribution": "store",
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "ios": {
        "credentialsSource": "remote"
      },
      "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "production"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "staging": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "***",
        "ascAppId": "***"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "***",
        "ascAppId": "***"
      }
    }
  }
}

Here’s my package.json (relevant parts only):
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "start:dev-client": "npx expo start --dev-client",
    "run:ios": "expo run:ios",
    "run:android": "expo run:android",
    "run:web": "expo start --web",
    "install-on:ios": "npx expo start --ios",
    "install-on:android": "npx expo start --android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~51.0.38",
    "expo-av": "~14.0.7",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.5",
    "expo-checkbox": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.28",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-image": "~1.13.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~7.0.5",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-updates": "~0.25.25",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

Here’s my app.json (relevant parts only):
{
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "description": "description",
  "platforms": [
    "ios",
    "android",
    "web"
  ],
  "web": {
    "bundler": "metro",
    "output": "static",
    "backgroundColor": "#121212",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/storyboard/production-app-splash.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#121212",
      "resizeMode": "contain"
    },
    "shortName": "Placeholder",
    "favicon": "./assets/images/storyboard/production-favicon.png",
    "themeColor": "#121212"
  },
  "assetBundlePatterns": [
    "**/*",
    "assets/**/*"
  ],
  "name": "Project Name",
  "owner": "placeholder",
  "slug": "placeholder",
  "android": {
    "splash": {
      "backgroundColor": "#121212",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "image": "./assets/images/storyboard/production-app-splash.png"
    },
    "adaptiveIcon": {
      "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/storyboard/production-app-adaptive-icon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "package": "com.placeholder.app_production",
    "icon": "./assets/images/storyboard/production-app-icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#121212",
    "versionCode": 1
  },
  "ios": {
    "usesIcloudStorage": false,
    "usesAppleSignIn": false,
    "accessesContactNotes": false,
    "infoPlist": {
      "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
      "CFBundleSignature": "placeholder",
      "CFBundleIdentifier": "com.placeholder.app-production",
      "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
        "NSExceptionDomains": {}
      }
    },
    "backgroundColor": "#121212"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@logrocket/react-native",
    "expo-font",
    "expo-secure-store",
    "expo-router",
    [
      "expo-screen-orientation",
      {
        "initialOrientation": "PORTRAIT"
      }
    ],
    [
      "expo-dev-launcher",
      {
        "launchModeExperimental": "most-recent"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "extra": {
    "APP_VARIANT": "production",
    "eas": {
      "projectId": "placeholder"
    },
    "env": {}
  },
  "scheme": "production",
  "icon": "./assets/images/storyboard/production-app-icon.png",
  "version": "1.0.3"
}

Here’s my app.config.ts:
import { envVariables } from "./assets/created-env-variables";
import { ExpoConfig } from "expo/config";

export const isEmpty = (value: unknown) =>
  value === undefined ||
  value === null ||
  (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
  (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0);

const appConfig = ({ config }): ExpoConfig => {
  let NSAppTransportSecurity = {
    NSAllowsArbitraryLoads: true,
    NSExceptionDomains: {
      "placeholder.com": { 
        NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads: true,
      },
      "placeholder.com": { 
        NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads: true,
      },
    },
  };

  let updates = {};

  if (envVariables.environment === "development" || envVariables.environment === "local") {
    NSAppTransportSecurity.NSExceptionDomains["placeholder.com"] = {
      NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads: true,
    };
  } else {
    updates = {
      url: "https://u.expo.dev/placeholder", 
    };
  }

  const iosConfig = config.ios || {};

  const getBundleIdentifier = (envType) => {
    switch(envType){
      case "production": {
        return "com.placeholder.app-production";
      }
      case "staging": {
        return "com.placeholder.app-staging";
      }
      case "development": {
        return "com.placeholder.app-development";
      }
      case "local": {
        return "com.placeholder.app-local";
      }
      default: {
        return "com.placeholder.app-production";
      }
    }
  };

  const supportsTablet = (envType) => {
    switch(envType){
      case "production": {
        return false;
      }
      case "staging": {
        return true;
      }
      case "development": {
        return true;
      }
      case "local": {
        return true;
      }
      default: {
        return false;
      }
    }
  };

  let modifiedConfig: ExpoConfig = {
    ...config,
    name: config.name || "app",
    slug: config.slug || "app",
    owner: "placeholder",
    extra: {
      "eas": {
        projectId: "placeholder",
      },
      ...config.extra,
      env: {
        ...envVariables
      }
    },
    ios: {
      ...iosConfig,
      bundleIdentifier: getBundleIdentifier(process.env.APP_ENV),
      supportsTablet: supportsTablet(process.env.APP_ENV),
      infoPlist: {
        ...iosConfig.infoPlist,
        NSAppTransportSecurity,
        NSFaceIDUsageDescription: "Will be used for authentication",
        NSMicrophoneUsageDescription: "Used for expo device package and Siri to play TV shows",
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      "@logrocket/react-native",
      "expo-font",
      "expo-secure-store",
      "expo-router",
      ["expo-screen-orientation", { initialOrientation: "PORTRAIT" }],
      "expo-asset",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          ios: {
            useFrameworks: "static",
          },
          android: {
            minSdkVersion: 21,
          },
        }
      ]
    ]
  };

  if (!isEmpty(updates)) {
    modifiedConfig.updates = updates;
  }

  const runtimeVersion = process.env.EXPO_RUNTIME_VERSION || "1.0.0";
  modifiedConfig.runtimeVersion = runtimeVersion;

  return modifiedConfig;
};

export default appConfig;

Note: Anything marked with "placeholder" is private information.
Questions:
How can I run a build on a simulator or physical device (outside of Expo Go) to capture logs and identify the issue causing the white screen?
What are the best steps to troubleshoot this problem?
The app works fine when running with npx expo start, but I encounter issues when building with EAS or running it locally in Xcode (the Hermes error in Xcode and the white screen on TestFlight).

The white screen may means there is a crash issue in the actual App that not replicated in Expo Go.
You can try running the actual App build in your simulator to find out:
npx expo prebuild --clean
npx expo run:ios

